# SQL Column A to Column B Comparison

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to determine how many times the same value in column A has the same corresponding value in Column B? I need something to look at the same values in column A and see if their corresponding B values are equal. In the example below, for all 164 in Col A their B values do not match. For 25, their B values do match. For 13, their B values do match. So the result of this should return 2/3 since 2 out of the 3 values in Column A match. How do I get this to work for hundreds of rows?

```
Col A        Col B   
--------------------
 164          42  
 164          51  
 164          13  
 25           10  
 25           10  
 13            4  
 13            4
```

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself? And can you show what you want the output to be?

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: What is meant by what platform? I am using Microsoft Access and have all the data in 1 table.

Comment: then your platform is ms-access, I've added the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using nested `group by`.  Here is MS Access SQL:

```
select avg(AllSame)
from (select colA,
             iif(min(colB) = max(colB), 1.0, 0.0) as AllSame
      from table as t
      group by colA
     ) as t;
```

The subquery produces a flag that specifies whether all the values are the same or not for each value in `colA`.  The outer query then calculates the proportion.

Comment: @user3922483 . . . Your original question was tagged "sql".  I "ms-access"ified the code.  Yuck.

Answer (score 1):

Basic way to see counts:

```
SELECT A.A,
       COUNT(A.A) AS NUM_A,
       COUNT(B.B) AS NUM_B_MATCH,
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON A.A = B.B 
GROUP BY A.A
```

Get 2/3

```
SELECT SUM(iff(B.B IS NOT NULL,1,0)) / COUNT(A.A) AS Percent
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON A.A = B.B
```

Comment: All of the data is in 1 table called Auto. Why am I joining 2 tables?

Comment: @user3922483 - I am joining the table to itself to get all combinations of column A to column B -- as you describe in your question.

Comment: This is the same thing @GordonLinoff is doing, but he is doing it with a sub-query and I'm doing it with a join.  Different platforms will optimize / perform better with different techniques.

Comment: This is giving me a syntax error too - I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @user3922483 - yeah it is in sql not ms-access.... edited but I don't have access around to test.